# Express router - Why is this route with parameters not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm confused by this. Why can I see this at the url http://localhost:1337/admin/hello/holly but not at the url http://localhost:1337/admin/users/holly? It's sending text right? the res.send (sending 'hello' to the page). But surely the adminRouter.get should be pulling the 2nd url (with the word 'users' in the path) ?  It's basically doing the opposite of what I 'm expecting it to do.

Here's the code snippet.

```
// route with parameters (http://localhost:1337/admin/users/:name)
    adminRouter.get('/users/:name', function(req, res) {
        res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + '!');
    });
```

** edit: Here's the whole code with the other routes:

```
// load the express package and create our app
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

// send our index.html file to the user for the home page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

    // get an instance of the router
    var adminRouter = express.Router();

   // route middleware that will happen on every request
    adminRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {

        // log each request to the console
        console.log(req.method, req.url);

        // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
        next(); 
    });
// route middleware to validate :name
    adminRouter.param('name', function(req, res, next, name) {
        // do validation on name here
        // blah blah validation
        // log something so we know its working
        console.log('doing name validations on ' + name);
        // once validation is done save the new item in the req
        req.name = name;
        // go to the next thing
        next();
    });
// route with parameters (http://localhost:1337/admin/users/:name)
    adminRouter.get('/users/:name', function(req, res) {
        res.send('hello ' + req.params.name + '!');
    });

    // create routes for the admin section
    // admin main page. the dashboard
    adminRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('I am the dashboard!');
    });

    // users page
    adminRouter.get('/users', function(req, res) {
        res.send('I show all the users!');
    });

    // posts page
    adminRouter.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
        res.send('I show all the posts!');
    });

    // apply the routes to our application
    app.use('/admin', adminRouter);

// start the server
app.listen(1337);
console.log('1337 is the magic port!');
```

Comment: Do you have any other routes? What are they? Another route may be matching before this one.

Comment: Yes, ah interesting, see my edit above (code added).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your question. Did you mean, you can't open  http://localhost:1337/admin/hello/holly ?

Comment: Also, which version of Express? I've copied your code verbatim and ran it with Express 4.12.4 and it seems to work. http://localhost:1337/admin/hello/holly does NOT work, and http://localhost:1337/admin/users/holly DOES work (prints 'hello holly!') which is the reverse of what you've described.

Comment: Express 4.12.4 . This is so completely weird, I stopped and restarted the server, and it's now working how I thought it should. Now if I use the word 'hello' in the url, I get the error `Cannot GET /admin/hello/holly` and if I use 'users' in the url it prints 'hello holly!' to the page. So, it's now working as expected.   Why would it do the opposite before I restarted? 

Very strange. Also the terminal was saying the server is restarting every time I save the file, so, I'm surprised manually stopping and restarting fixed it.

No Bidhan, I meant the opposite, but it's working now. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this one was to just manually restart my server and the problem corrected itself.

Why it had gotten itself in a twist and was doing the reverse of what it should have been doing who knows, but on restarting the server it worked correctly.